# Time based scheduling, NTP vs delay()

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, millis

Without asking an open-ended question, i wish to find the best way (resourcefulness) to execute methods from an arduino based on time.

in a nutshell, every 10 minutes i want functionA() to be called & every 30 minutes, functionB(). At this point i'm unable to specifiy whether a method would need to be called at a less frequent rate, however i wish to assume that one may.

My 2 ideas so far:

- encapsulate the functions a & b inside the NTP client, and execute based on the minutes in an hour

**or**

- use delay() or even the milli() counter with functions a & b below inside the loop.

My main worry of the 2nd option is that the arduino handles time keeping itself, in a long run (lets say 1 year), the arduino will end up with no memory left. Whats is the consensus with this?

Board wise, to be run on Uno & Mega.

Comment: You may want to separate the task of keeping time from the task of running some function at even intervals in your mind, they are different problems.

Answer (score 1):

memory used by delay() and milli() (if any) will be recycled every time you call it, so it does not add up. You should be aware that milli rolls over (resets back to 0) after approximately 50 days - see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Millis - you will need to keep track of how many times it has overflowed, and include that in your calculations.

delay will only be useful if you do NOTHING AT ALL during that time - if you want to do other stuff in that space, you should use milli(). Also, if you delay (without using milli()), your events will drift by the time it takes to run the code. delay() and milli() will also only be as accurate as the crystal on your arduino - it should be no more than 20 parts per million; this comes to 10 minutes per year. This may or may not be a problem.

NTP will use a lot more resources, and has to be polled. It is also potentially less reliable (i.e. NTP may be down for short periods).

If you need accurate timing, the best solution would be to use delay() to pass the time (approximately), milli() to keep the time, and adjust for drift with NTP.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a battery backed up Real-Time clock to your arduino and use that to keep track of the time.

Basically the same idea as NTP but minimal hardware is required and you can get an RTC with the long term accuracy you need.

Answer (score 1):

Both NTP and milli() waste a lot of processing as it keeps the Arduino busy checking if the time is right.

Your best bet is to use the Arduino timer. Set the timer to interrupt every 10 minutes. If you don't need to do anything aside from functions A and B, you can let your Arduino sleep and keep power draw to a minimum.

```
// Example code
void funcA(){
    // do stuff
}
void funcB(){
    // do stuff
}

void setup() {

    // initialize Timer1
    cli();          // disable global interrupts
    TCCR1A = 0;     // clear TCCR1A
    TCCR1B = 0;     // same for TCCR1B

    // set compare match register to desired timer count:
    // 15624*1024/16000000 = 1sec at 16MHz
    OCR1A = 15624;   
    // turn on CTC mode:
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);
    // use 1/1024 the speed of the clock:
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10);
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);
    // enable timer compare interrupt:
    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);
    // enable global interrupts:
    sei();
}

ISR(TIM1_COMPA_vect) 
// Your task manager here
// This function decides when to execute the functions A and B
{
    static t1= 0;
    static t2= 0;

    // increment your counter flags
    t1++;
    t2++;

    if (t1==10) {//runs function every 10 sec
        funcA();
        t1=0;
    }
    if (t2==30) {//runs function every 30 sec
        funcB();
        t2=0;
    }
}

void loop(){

    // do stuff or sleep for even more power saving
}
```

Hope this helps.